# Infinite scrolling feature in syncfysion file manager angular component

Tags: angular, infinite-scroll, syncfusion, file-manager

Can we implement infinite scrolling feature in syncfusion file manager angular component? e.g. If we have more than 10000 files in one folder then when we try to open the folder it will take more time as we have more than 10000 files. So it takes much time to get the API response. I don't want to load all files initially. Is it possible to get specific amounts of files initially and when user scrolles we call another API to get another files?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have already considered Virtual loading support in File Manager component as a feature at our end. Usually, Syncfusion will plan and implement the features based on feature rank, customer requested count and volume wish-list. We will implement and include this feature in any of our upcoming releases.

You can track the status through the [link](https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/13922/impove-filemanagers-performance).